# Error running servlet on google app engine after deploying

Tags: java, google-app-engine

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This feature is only available to backend instances.
    at com.google.appengine.api.system.SystemServiceImpl.translateException(SystemServiceImpl.java:40)
    at com.google.appengine.api.system.SystemServiceImpl.startBackgroundRequest(SystemServiceImpl.java:28)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$BackgroundThreadFactory.newThread(ApiProxyImpl.java:1125)
    at com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread(ThreadManager.java:88)
    at newscrawler.crawlerServlet.doGet(crawlerServlet.java:22)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You've just dumped a massive stack-trace. This is not a question. Do you have the code that generated this trace?

Comment: i have the code yes, but i forgot to post it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to create a background thread on frontend instance via [`ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager#createBackgroundThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29http://). This method can only be called by code running on [backend instances](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview).

Instead try using `ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest()`. This thread will run in parallel to your request, but the limitation is that it can not outlive the request that started it.